# How would I go about inserting some new values into a specific collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert some new values into some documents that already exist in a collection called "matches". For each of the matches I want to insert upvote: 0 and downvote: 0. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this in my document. Right now I'm trying to do it with a specific _id just for testing to make sure I can do it correctly, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. as I'm getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined.

```
 upvote: function(req, res, next){
    let userId = db.get().collection('users').findOne({"_id": ObjectId("5b6a39ff17e9af6c20b9c5a8")});
    let gameId = db.get().collection('matches').findOne({"_id": ObjectId("5b7b67247a3b516f8cb0c7d9")})

    userId.then(function(upvotedata){
        if(upvotedata){



            console.log(upvotedata._id);

        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    });
    gameId.then(function(game){
        if(game){
            db.matches.insert({$set: {upvote: 0, downvote: 0}})
        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: First: do you mean `db.get().collection('matches').insert(...)`? Second, you don't want to perform an `insert()`, you want to perform an `update()`. From the MongoDB shell, it would look like `db.matches.update({}, {$set: {upvote: 0, downvote: 0}}, {multi: true})`. You'll need to modify your query to match the syntax for your driver version.

Comment: @B.Fleming so I need to update() in the terminal Mongodb shell?